# Factorize $\rho(b^5 - a^5)$ to get a term with $\rho(b^3 - a^3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am trying to factorise $\rho(b^5 - a^5)$ so that I have a term $\rho(b^3 - a^3)$.
I have a value $M = \rho(b^3 - a^3)$ that I am trying to replace $\rho$ with so when i tried to factorise it like this: $$\rho[(b^3 - a^3)(b^2 + a^2) + b^2a^3 - b^3a^2]$$ it does not work since it creates more $\rho$ values.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A general tip: put \$ signs at the ends of expression, not in between. For example, `$\rho(b^5 - a^5)$` for  $\rho(b^5 - a^5)$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in general to factor the $b^5-a^5$ term and leave a $b^3-a^3$ term.
$$b^5-a^5=(b-a)(b^4+b^3a+b^2a^2+ba^3+a^4)$$
but the latter term cannot be reduced any further. Since a $b^3-a^3$ term cannot be pulled out cleanly, the task you assigned yourself is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I must've made a mistake in my calculations before.